# Android/Jitpack: Unable to import submodule

Tags: android, import, module, jitpack

I'm trying to import a submodule of an android library I'm creating. The sub-module is called **progressbar**

https://jitpack.io/#SomeKoder/Essentials/0.1.0

https://github.com/SomeKoder/Essentials

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.SomeKoder:Essentials:0.1.0'
}
```

I've tried this and many other variations without success.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.SomeKoder.Essentials:progressbar:0.1.0'
}
```

Can someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong please?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this to the modules **build.gradle** led to the artifacts actually building:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release

                groupId = 'com.somekoder.Essentials.progressbar'
                artifactId = 'progressbar'
                version = '0.1.4'
            }
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                from components.debug

                groupId = 'com.somekoder.Essentials.progressbar'
                artifactId = 'progressbar-debug'
                version = '0.1.4'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems you must add a variant of this code in every module you wish to create an artifact for. Then importing through JitPack works fine.